# Generalize Integral

Tags: integration, power-series

Any examples were the equation

$$\int_0^{u}F(x) \ dx+I(0)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(F_n(u))u^{n+1}(-1)^n}{(n+1)!}$$

fails.

F(x) is restricted such that F(x) is defined in the interval 0 to u. So F(x)=1/x will not satisfy the equation since 1/0 is undefined; but F(x=)1/(x+1) will do, since F(0)=1/(0+1)=1.

$F_n(u)$ is the nth derivative of F(x) evaluated at u. 
I(0)= constant.

I've only try f(x) as simple expressions such as atan(x), sin(x), cos(x), e^x. Also few complex expressions of personal interest such as cos(x)/(x+1) and sin(x)/x, could not find a failure.  Appreciate any feedback.

The equation can be derived by continuous integration of the right hand side integral of the trivial equation:

$$\int F(x) \ dx= xF(x)-\int xF_1(x)$$

Still working on visualization apparently the RHS integral is the y intercept of the tangent line of the function under the integral at (x=0).  Hence allowing construction of the integral using the derivative.

For $f(x) =e^{-1/x^2}, the result is as follows:

$$\int_{0}^{y} e^{-1/x^{2}}+I(0)=ye^{-1/y^{2}}+e^{-1/y^{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{inf}\frac{2^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!!}\left (\frac{1}{x}  \right )^{2n+1}$$

$$I(0)=1.7724538509={\pi }^{1/2}$$

But derivation is much-much-much easier following the RHS integral

$$\int F(x) \ dx= xF(x)-\int xF_1(x)$$

Comment: What is $Fn(x)$?

Comment: Fn(x) is the nth derivative of F(x).

Comment: Why are you insisting on using unconventional notation and why have you removed the edits?  And your use of the same designation for the integration "dummy" variable and the upper integration limit creates ambiguity.

Comment: Why have you removed the edits? Not so, I only know how to post. No idea on edits.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your notation so the question makes sense: you want to find an example so that the following derivation **fails**:
\begin{align} f(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x-x_0)^n \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}\\
\int_{0}^{x_0} f(x) \, dx &= \int_0^{x_0}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x-x_0)^n \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!} \,dx
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{x_0}(x-x_0)^n\, dx \cdot \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[\frac{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_0^{x_0}\cdot \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[\frac{(0)^{n+1} - (-x_0)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_0^{x_0}\cdot \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{ x_0^{n+1} f^{(n)}(x_0)}{(n+1)!}
\end{align}

We could take one of two approaches to "break" this. We could choose some function with a Taylor series that doesn't have "good" convergence characteristics on $(0,x_0)$. Alternatively, and perhaps more simply, we could choose a function that fails to be equal to its own Taylor series, for instance

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/(x-x_0)^2} & \text{if $x\neq x_0$}\\ 0 & \text{if $x = x_0$}\end{cases}$$

This is infinitely differentiable everywhere and $f^{(n)}(x_0)=0$ for all $n$, which is a good exercise to prove. So its Taylor series centered at $x_0$ is identically zero. However, $f(x) > 0$ for all $x\neq x_0$, so

$$\int_0^{x_0} f(x)\,dx > 0,$$
but
$$ \int_0^{x_0} \underbrace{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x-x_0)^n \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!} }_{=0} \,dx = 0$$

Comment: You have $x_0$ = 0. So $$\int_0^{x_0} f(x)\,dx = \int_0^{0} f(x)\,dx=0$$.

Comment: $f^{(n)}(1)=-2/e$.

Comment: @926reals Firstly, integration of any function over any point, e.g., $\{0\}$, is going to always be zero, so the problem statement should include the requirement $x_0 \neq 0$.

Comment: @926reals Secondly, why are you evaluating at $1$? Take any $x\neq x_0$, then
\begin{align}f'(x_0) &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}\\ &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ e^{-\tfrac{1}{(x_0+h-x_0)^2}} - 0}{h}\\& = \lim_{1/h=u\to \pm\infty} ue^{-u^2} = 0
\end{align}
It's easy then to show (by induction), that
$$\frac{d^nf(x)}{dx^n} \sim O\left(\frac{e^{-\tfrac{1}{(x-x_0)^2}}}{(x-x_0)^{n+2}}\right)
\overset{x\to x_0}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

Comment: While it is very difficult to obtain the derivatives of $e^{-1/x^2}$ The result of the equation yields:$$\int_{0}^{y} e^{-1/x^{2}}+I(0)=ye^{-1/y^{2}}+e^{-1/y^{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!!}\left (\frac{1}{x}  \right )^{2n+1}//$$   I(0) =1.7724538509

Comment: Your integration makes no sense. How is $x$ on the right hand side?

It might make more sense to reread my question using a slight notation change:
$$f_{x_0}(x) = \begin{cases} e^{1/(x-x_0)^2} & \text{if $x\neq x_0$}\\ 0 & \text{if $x=x_0$}\end{cases}$$

Then I have argued that $f_{x_0}^{(n)}(x_0) = 0$ for all $n$ derivatives, and therefore the Taylor series centered at $x_0$ is identically zero.

We then know that if $x\neq x_0$, $$\int_0^{x_0} f_{x_0}(x)\,dx > 0 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x_0^{n+1}\overbrace{f_{x_0}^{(n)}(x_0)}^{=\,0}}{(n+1)!}$$

Comment: @ adfriedman: You have $\int F(u(x))$
My question pertains only to $\int F(x)$.   The integral is defined by the derivative. However, I leaned the fact, F(u(x)) vs F(x) from your post. The derivatives are very different. As all can calculate, the equation I posted for your F(u(x)) is true.  Impressive showing of Taylor series, may or may not work for F(u(x)). What do I know! But try the equation. Absolutely correct.

Comment: @ adfriedman: So try finding a simple integral F(x) not F(U(x)).

Comment: Satisfying your new notation, let  $$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{(x-u)^2}} & \text{if $x \neq u$}\\ 0& \text{if $x=u$}  \end{cases}$$ Then my analysis works. If you want $f$ to be defined completely unrelated to $u$ then what you've ask for is not possible.

Comment: And $u$ should not be a function of $x$. You keep mixing up your variables of integration and variables in bounds of integration (and you have done this in many of your other posts). I recommend reviewing basic definitions rather than treating mathematics as a purely computational (and at that, wrong) exercise.